# Obtaining status from a remote executed process

Tags: c++, qt, libcurl, libssh, remote-execution

I am invoking a remote process using `libcURL`s [`libssh2`](http://www.libssh2.org/). The remote server is a Linux (CentOS) and the client is an Windows XP. Also am using Qt 4.6 and C++.The processes are some third party applications which will be invoked by `libssh2`

I am able to remotely execute a process using [libssh2_channel_exec()](http://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_channel_exec.html).

But how to obtain the status of the invoked process? Say for e.g like `PROCESS_STARTED` or `PROCESS_COMPLETED` or `PROCESS_RUNNING` or something like that.

Now `libssh2_channel_exec()` returns just `0` for success.

Is there any way I can obtain the status of such remote executed processes? Any pointers regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an invoker exective file? It calls the real remote process and output the remote process status. And now, you can call with `libssh2_channel_open_ex` to read exchanged data(remote process status) from remote server.

Comment: But then to obtain the status, I have to constantly poll the file over the network, right?

Comment: In my pinion, I'll write a C/S(comm. by SSH) to finish it.